# Why I get different length of vectors using gensim LSI model?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I'm trying to cluster some descriptions using LSI. As the dataset that I have is too long, I'm clustering based on the vectors obtained from the models instead of using the similarity matrix, which requires too much memory, and if I pick a sample, the matrix generated doesn't correspond to a square (this precludes the use of MDS).

However, after running the model and looking for the vectors I'm getting different vector's lengths in the descriptions. Most of them have a length of 300 (the num_topics argument in the model), but some few, with the same description, present a length of 299.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to correct it?

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(totalvocab_lemmatized)
dictionary.compactify()

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in totalvocab_lemmatized]

###tfidf model
tfidf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus, normalize = True)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]

###LSI model
lsi = gensim.models.LsiModel(corpus_tfidf, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=300)
vectors =[]
for n in lemmatized[:100]:
    vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(n)
    vec_lsi = lsi[vec_bow]
    print(len(vec_lsi))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit zeros are omitted, which is why some vectors appear shorter. 
Source: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2501